# Javascript window.navigator.standalone broken

Tags: javascript, web-applications, fullscreen

really annoying me now,

I've stripped my code down to this

```
$(function(){
  if ( ("standalone" in window.navigator) && !window.navigator.standalone ) {
    alert('full screen');
  }
});
```

yet every time I run this on my ipad FROM safari it kicks out the alert.

I've no idea why and its causing chaos to my whole uni project which is due monday! Any help would be amazing.

Comment: gah, I had different code before, without the ! and saw someone said this above code was more reliable. so i just swapped it out without noticing the ! thanks.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it so that your question doesn't appear in the `unanswered` tab.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When/if the web page is in standard/usual Safari mode, the "window.navigator.standalone" value will be False. Only when the web page is in "app mode/i.e. full screen mode", this value will be True. NOTE:  this JavaScript value does not exist in browsers that do not support "app mode/i.e. full screen mode". So you should test both for the very existence of the property window.navigator.standalone as well as for its truthfulness.

Comment: Im not getting it. Why simple if(navigator.standalone) will not work?
If property is not there it will still be false. If its there and false its false. If its there and true its true. Isnt it what expected?

Comment: @YaroslavYakovlev it could be that you are actually in an app, however this in-app browser may not support the standalone attribute. So you have three possible values: 

 - `false`: you are SURE that you are in a browser,
 - `true`: you are SURE that you are in an app, 
 - `undefined`: you are not sure about anything;